# error :object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to None

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Trying to Delete an object using shell in django. How do i delete the object say "Ron"?

**I use the following command:**

```
t.delete('Ron')
```

Comment: What is `t` here?

Comment: It looks to me that you *never* saved it in the first place.

Comment: I suspect OP is doing `t = Model(name="Ron")` and thinking this is doing a get rather than instantiating a new object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error:

> object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to None

Suggests that you either never saved the object `t` in the first place, or you changed the primary key (here `id`) to `None` manually.

If you have a single object you can perform a `.delete()` on the object, for example:

```
my_obj = Model.objects.get(name='Ron')
my_obj.delete()
```

You should *not* add extra parameters to `delete` except for `using` and `keep_parents`, as specified in the [documentation for **`Model.delete()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#deleting-objects)

Or you can delete the objects with a `.filter(..)` statement, like:

```
Model.objects.filter(name='Ron').delete()
```

this will delete *all* `Model` objects with name `'Ron'`.

Comment: this happened to me with [djongo](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo) which doesnt always create the primary key automatically